# Best way of dealing with Android text translations / app internationalization

Tags: android, android-studio, internationalization

I find it out that dealing with text translations in Android is difficult. There are some discussions about this topic, but I haven't found a definitive good solution yet. (which is weird since I believe there are tons of apps that need to manage translations. Also, I assume Google wants to provide better-quality apps and internationalization plays an important role in this)

What I am trying to achieve:

1. Extract strings.xml into an Excel that I can later share with others (translator, native person,..)
2. Convert that Excel file back into strings.xml

This is an ongoing process. As I am developing new features, more strings get added/changed, thus the above process needs to be repeated

Of course, there is the well-known Translations Editor in Android Studio. Unfortunately, with the new versions of IDE, it does not allow you to copy/paste data into Excel so you can later share it with others

There is the option of installing an older version of Android Studio from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive.html) that lets you copy/paste data from Translations Editor. (this is dumb in my opinion)

Also, I found other partial solutions:

1. A third-party plugin that converts .xml to .csv ([link here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7782-android-strings-xml-to-csv-converter)). Unfortunately, it does not seem to work anymore
2. [A website](https://asrt.gluege.boerde.de/) that takes your strings.xml as an input, and provides translated strings.xml in any language you choose (it users Google Translate). - not exactly what I need
3. [Another website](https://json-csv.com/xml) where you can upload the strings.xml and get the .csv file. - it partially solves my problem

What would be ideal for me is a version of Translations Editor that is online and can be edited by multiple persons at the same time

**Does this solution exist? How are you dealing with this issue?**

Comment: Our localization team both fetches and delivers the translations through git. I have no idea what kind of tools they are using in between though, but creating a (kotlin) script that converts from xml <-> csv shouldn't be too much of a hassle.